# Force and Vector question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors

> *A force of 6 Newton and another 8 newton can be applied together to produce the effect of a single force of  a) 1 N b) 11 N c) 15 N d) 20 N.*

More generally, if I know the magnitude of one force, say $F_1$, and another, say $F_2$, then how do I find the magnitude of the resultant total force of the two vectors? Is it even possible? And if it is, what do I do? Do I add them up together, or something like that?.

Comment: This is too localised. And you have not even shown what you have done so far.

Comment: The answer is (B) because if they were anti-parallel, they net force would be 2 Newtons, and if they were parallel, the force would be 14 Newtons. Choices (A), (C), and (D) fall outside of this range. Also, bad question.

Comment: Hi @Anusha: The constraints that Greg is talking about is aka. as [triangle inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Answer (score 6):

I'll risk answering a homework problem since I think there's a principle that we experimental physicists take for granted, but which may not be obvious to budding physicists.

When doing experiments it's not uncommon for the experimenter to have no way of knowing if a result is correct, but you can usually work out whether it's reasonable. If you look at the question this way, you could word it as:

> Starting with two forces, 6N and 8N, I've measured a force, $F$. How can I know if this is a physically reasonable result and not just a badly done experiment?

I think this is what the question is getting at, and it's testing your knowledge of vector addition.

The way you answer this is to have some mathematical model for predicting the results of your experiment. If your answer falls outside the range predicted by your model then it's probably wrong. In this question the experiment is to add two forces, and for our model we're going to assume that the forces are combined by vector addition.

[image: Vectoraddition]

In this case the magnitude of $F_r$ is given by:

$$ F_r = \sqrt{F_1^2 + F_2^2 + 2F_1F_2 \space cos \theta} $$

(I won't prove this as you can find it in any textbook on vector addition, or look up the cosine rule). Now, we told what $F_1$ and $F_2$ are (8N and 6N) so what values can $F_r$ take? Well if we just use the above equation and let $\theta$ run from zero to $2\pi$ we get:

[image: Model results]

So we find that in our model $F_r$ has a minimum value of 2N, when $\theta = \pi$ and a maximum value of 14N, when $\theta = 0$ or $2\pi$. This means that the results (a), (c) and (d) must be wrong because they lie outside the range our model predicts. The only possible result is (b).

Answer (score -1):

this question was poorly stated.. there are factors to be considered for us to be able to know  the resultant force. such as angle of the two forces to each other, and their positions. if they were parallel or perpendicular. none of them were stated. you even did not help your self to know or to find the answer. you just post it here and let anyone answer it. this type of question can be closed immediately.. well, if there is angle given, you can get the resultant by `F=sqrt[Fx^2+Fy^2]` wherein Fx is the summation of all components of x and Fy is the summation of all components of y.

Comment: Well, you just know how to discourage others! This question might not be a good question or as good as to be on this site; nevertheless, there is obviously an answer to the question which can surely be determined without even knowing the angle as has been beautifully done by John Rennie.